# Open OneNote quick notes automatically on startup?

Tags: windows, microsoft-onenote-2016

I use `Windows+N` to create OneNote **Quick Notes** on a regular basis, to create little to-do lists or other one-off notes, such that I often have a few open on my desktop. Is there a way to have OneNote automatically open all of those Quick Notes again on startup? i.e. if I have 5 Quick Note windows open on my desktop, and need to reboot, is there a way to get OneNote to open those 5 notes again when the computer restarts, without having to go in and manually open them one by one?

I'd expected this to be a common question, but to my surprise I didn't see anyone else asking it. If I'm wrong, and this is a duplicate, apologies in advance...

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is not possible. OneNote doesn't have this as a feature. This leaves two primary ways to open a specific OneNote page (automatically):

1. By opening a shortcut link file pointing to the specific page (easy).
2. With a keyboard automation tool such as [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (hard).

Regardless of which method you use, both require knowledge of the specific page you wish to open.

Your best option is to use the workaround described below to open the OneNote *Section* containing your notes. This would at least minimize the number of clicks required to get to the specific pages you're interested in.

---

You can accomplish this by saving shortcuts in your Startup folder as follows:

1. In OneNote, right-click the page/section/notebook you want to open on startup and click **Copy Link to Page**

   [image]
2. In Start, search for `shell:startup` to open your user Startup folder

   [image]
3. Right-click on a blank part of the File Explorer window and click **New** then **Shortcut**

   [image]
4. In the *Type the location of the item:* field paste the link to your page you copied to the Clipboard in step 1 then click **Next**.

   [image]
5. Finish the wizard. The next time you log in your OneNote page will open automatically.

As an added bonus, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to the shortcuts icons you created in your Startup folder. This lets you quickly go to any location in OneNote regardless of where you are in Windows. To do this, right-click the shortcut file, choose **Properties** then select the *Shortcut key* field and press your desired key combination.

Comment: This works if I always want to open the exact same set of notes, every time, forever. But I want OneNote to open whatever notes happen to have been open at the time. I'm constantly creating new notes, deleting ones i'm done with, etc. I don't want to have to create a startup script every time I create one (and delete it every time I delete the corresponding note).

Comment: @sernaferna Answer updated. Unfortunately what you're asking isn't possible. It's a good idea though.